# Google Maps API V3 Add a button near to a polygon hovered

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, hover

I'm working with Google Maps API V3, and I'd like to display a clickable image near to a drawed polygon when the mouse hovers it.
Until now, I'm able to create this event, but I have no idea how to display this image near to my polygon. Ideally, I'd like this image appears where the mouse entered in the polygon.

Here is a piece of my code, but it's just a try and the image is not displayed, so it is very incomplete (and maybe wrong). You can suggest me to do otherwise, Javascript is not my preferred language...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mouseover', function(e) {
    this.setOptions( {fillOpacity: 0.1} );

    polygon["btnMyButtonClickHandler"] = {};
    polygon["btnMyButtonImageUrl"] = MyImage;
    displayMyButton(polygon);
});

function displayMyButton(polygon) {
    var path = polygon.getPath();
    var myButton = getMyButton(path.btnMyButtonImageUrl);

    if(myButton.length === 0) 
    {
        console.log("IN"); //Is displayed in the console
        var myImg= $("img[src$='http://linkToMyImage.png']");

        myImg.parent().css('height', '21px !important');
        myImg.parent().parent().append('<div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 27px;top:21px;"><img src="' + path.btnMyButtonImageUrl+ '" class="myButtonClass" style="height:auto; width:auto; position: absolute; left:0;"/></div>');

    // now get that button back again!
    myButton = getMyButton(path.btnMyButtonImageUrl);
    myButton.hover(function() { 
        $(this).css('left', '-30px'); return false; }, 
        function() { $(this).css('left', '0px'); return false; });
    myButton.mousedown(function() { $(this).css('left', '-60px'); return false;});
    }

    // if we've already attached a handler, remove it
    if(path.btnDeleteClickHandler) 
        myButton.unbind('click', path.btnMyButtonClickHandler);

    myButton.click(path.btnMyButtonClickHandler);
}

function getMyButton(imageUrl) {
    return  $("img[src$='" + imageUrl + "']");
}
```

Thanks for your suggestions !

---

**EDIT**

@MrUpsidown, unfortunately no, `click event` can't be a solution, I really need your Something here div appears at `mouseover`.
I modified your code like this :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygonPath, 'mouseover', function (event) {
    if( $("#map_overlay").css('display') == "none")
    {
        $("#map_overlay").css({
                               'position': 'absolute',
                               'display': 'block',
                               'left': event.Sa.pageX,
                               'top': event.Sa.pageY
                              });
     }
 });
```

The div appears when my mouse enter the polygon and *don't move* except if my mouse hovers the div (which hovers the polygon). On this case, the event seems called continuously. How can we avoid this and let the div at its inital position once the mouse enter the polygon ?
Here is your modified : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrC2D/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an element to hold your clickable image. Make it `position:absolute;` with a bigger z-index than your map container. To place it at a specific place, check the mouse position on your polygon `mouseover` event and set the element position accordingly. Hope this helps.

**Edit:** Yes, wrap it in a DIV is a good idea. Here is a simple fiddle to show the concepts. And sorry, of course it was `mouseover` and not `mouseenter` like I first wrote.

http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/zrC2D/

Comment: I don't really know how to create the element which will hold my clickable image, could you provide me a little piece of code ? I tried to encapsulate it in a `<div>` but nothing appears on screen...

Comment: Ok thank you very much, it's really easier than what I was trying to do... Last point before accepting your answer : Your "something here" div follows your mouse pointer, whereas I need to be clicked. How can you stop the div moving once the pointer is inside the polygon ? Is there any easy css trick ?

Comment: Well, that's the problem with mouseover... The event is fired continuously when your mouse moves over the polygon. I would consider showing the DIV on click. Could that be a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately it can't. Please take a look to Edit section of my initial post and the modified JSfiddle I link.

Comment: Ok I finally find a solution. I'll update your jsfiddle in some hours. Thank you for showing me the way to achieve this !!

Comment: Would you consider using the native infowindow object? What I do there is that I remove the `mouseover` listener once the infowindow is shown (domready), and bind the listener again on map `mousemouse` which is only fired outside of the polygon. I am also setting a variable to `true` or `false` so that it doesn't get fired continously. http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/zrC2D/6/